# How to display JSON data into HTML web page (request works in console)

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch-api

I have some basic HTML with a small script that fetches information from endpoint and retrieves information about videos.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Covid-19 Stats- UK</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-3" style="width: 450px;">
        <h2 class="text-center">Videos</h2>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>title</th>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>duration</th>
                <th>length</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="title"></td>
                <td id="id"></td>
                <td id="duration"></td>
                <td id="length"></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

```js
const options = {method: 'GET', headers: {Accept: 'application/json', Authorization: 'API-KEY'}};

fetch('https://api.synthesia.io/v2/videos', options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I retrive the information fine in the console:

```
createdAt: 1652951825
description: "How to create your custom avatar"
duration: "0:01:01a.000"
id: "5099a5c5-ca44-412a-a4b3-da9fbe24da04"
lastUpdatedAt: 1652954240
status: "complete"
title: "Creating your custom avatar"
visibility: "private"
```

But i'm struggling with how to map this into my table.

Comment: _"But i'm struggling with how to map this into my table."_: add your code struggles to your question as a [mcve] so we can help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

In case You have a single video response

```js
let data = {
    createdAt: 1652951825,
    description: "How to create your custom avatar",
    duration: "0:01:01a.000",
    id: "5099a5c5-ca44-412a-a4b3-da9fbe24da04",
    lastUpdatedAt: 1652954240,
    status: "complete",
    title: "Creating your custom avatar",
    visibility: "private"
}

document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = data.title;
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = data.id;
document.getElementById("duration").innerHTML = data.duration;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Covid-19 Stats- UK</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container mt-3" style="width: 450px;">
        <h2 class="text-center">Videos</h2>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>title</th>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>duration</th>
                    <th>length</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td id="title"></td>
                    <td id="id"></td>
                    <td id="duration"></td>
                    <td id="length"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Or If you got an array of data, you can try

```js
        let data = {
            vodeos: [{
                    createdAt: 1652951825,
                    description: "How to create your custom avatar",
                    duration: "0:01:01a.000",
                    id: "5099a5c5-ca44-412a-a4b3-da9fbe24da04",
                    lastUpdatedAt: 1652954240,
                    status: "complete",
                    title: "Creating your custom avatar",
                    visibility: "private"
                },
                {
                    createdAt: 1652951825,
                    description: "How to create your custom avatar",
                    duration: "0:01:01a.000",
                    id: "5099a5c5-ca44-412a-a4b3-da9fbe24da04",
                    lastUpdatedAt: 1652954240,
                    status: "complete",
                    title: "Creating your custom avatar",
                    visibility: "private"
                }
            ]
        }

        data.vodeos.forEach(video => {
            let row = `<tr>
                        <td>${video.title}</td>
                        <td>${video.id}</td>
                        <td>${video.duration}</td>
                        <td>${video.length}</td>
                    </tr>`;
            document.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML += row;
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Covid-19 Stats- UK</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container mt-3" style="width: 450px;">
        <h2 class="text-center">Videos</h2>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>title</th>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>duration</th>
                    <th>length</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

I'm still a little lost on how to get the data into the table - that's the missing step.

Whilst I see this in the console.

createdAt: 1652951825,
description: "How to create your custom avatar",

I'm unsure how to get this into the table - as the JSON will change.